# Relative Layout Gravity not Working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Here is the **XML** file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/whitebar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Here is the **Java** File

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
    int images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};

    relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(images[getRandomNumber()]);
}


private int getRandomNumber() {
    //Note that general syntax is Random().nextInt(n)
    //It results in range 0-4
    //So it should be equal to number of images in images[] array
    return new Random().nextInt(4);
}}
```

`The code above gives an output` [image: Current Output]

`BUT` what i would like to happen is similar to this [image: prospected]

How can set the exact location for my white bar image because Relative Layout Gravity not Working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layout gravity is used with linear layouts.

what you want to use is alignParentBottom

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/whitebar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer still i have the problem. please see this. [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XVJSj.png)  i think the problem is because of that blue rectangle? how to fix that?

Comment: add android:scaleType="fitXY" to the imageview

Answer (score 2):

you should remove gravity and put in the ImageView

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer still i have the problem. please see this. [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XVJSj.png)  i think the problem is because of that blue rectangle? how to fix that?